# How to convert a list to a set in sagemath?

Tags: sagemath

I am trying to convert a list to a set in **sagemath 8.2**

```
H = Set(range(1,n+1))

[1, 2, 3, 4]

L=Combinations(H,2).list()

[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Now, I would like to use **SetPartitions** but `L` is a `list`.

How can I convert this list to set?

Comment: set(L) or Set(L) depending if you want a Python set or a Sage set. Or set([set(x) for x in L]) if you want it nested. Seems to me SetPartitions can operate on lists too.

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980901/how-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-in-sagemath). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/267099

Answer (score 1):

The items of the list `L` are lists themselves. Being mutable,
lists are not hashable, and therefore cannot be used as elements
in a set, so we turn them into tuples first.

```
sage: n = 3
sage: H = Set(range(1, n+1))
sage: H
{1, 2, 3}
sage: L = Combinations(H, 2).list()
sage: L
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
sage: M = set(tuple(c) for c in L)
sage: M
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
sage: SetPartitions(M)
Set partitions of {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
sage: P = SetPartitions(M)
sage: P
Set partitions of {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
sage: for p in P:
....:     print p
....:
{{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}}
{{(1, 2)}, {(1, 3), (2, 3)}}
{{(1, 2), (2, 3)}, {(1, 3)}}
{{(1, 2), (1, 3)}, {(2, 3)}}
{{(1, 2)}, {(1, 3)}, {(2, 3)}}
```